# Facebook app as tab

Tags: facebook

My app tab is not visible in my app page. I did following steps, but app is not visible.

```
1) Created app from https://developers.facebook.com/apps/
2) Added all fields to Page Tab configuration
```

But I cannot see tab in my application facebook page (https://www.facebook.com/apps/application.php?id=appid).

Comment: That is the Application profile page. To add the tab to a page you need to use the Add to my page link on the bottom-left menu on that page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to do as @DannyKK says, then head to the Apps section of your Page administration,  and find your app in the list. Click 'edit settings', then on the Profile tab of the resulting dialog you'll have the option to finally add the custom tab to your page.

I find the process wildly unintuitive. Possibly it's been streamlined and the step DannyKK didn't mention is no longer necessary, but just in case...

Comment: Can I create test pages in Facebook? I don't have admin rights to page that should add this app, so i have to test how to add tab.

Comment: I don't think there's an official way - just make a Page and don't publish it. You add the Tab in the same way as for the real Page. There's no harm in having the Tab installed on both Pages at once either.